# Constraints - Constrained Target

Tags: mdriven

I have some DroopyEyes code that expects ConstrainedTargetName to be not null.
However the constraint I have a problem with deals with a relation and not an attribute.The ContrainedTarget dropdown only lists attributes.

What is the significance and use of the "Constrained Target"?

TIA
Steve AU

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correct the "Constrained Target" is an indicator on where to put the "broken constraint"-flag when the constraint is broken. So if there is a ui-Widget that shows self.Something and you have the Constrained target set to "Something" the error-indicator will be lit on this when this constraint is broken.

Since there are no simple UI-widgets for associations the "Constrained target" only allows attributes.

In newer MDriven we rely on the Validation-expressions in the ViewModel to associate error with UI widgets (even comboboxes and datagrids).